# Spring Boot with Quartz Scheduler: Clustering not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am using the dependency spring-boot-starter-quartz and I have the following config in application.yaml for Quartz

```
  
spring: 
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceId: AUTO
          threadPool:
            threadCount: 2
          jobStore:
            class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
            useProperties: false
            tablePrefix: SCHEDULER_
            isClustered: true
            clusterCheckinInterval: 20000
```

I have the following beans defined in the Quartz configuration

```
    @Bean
    JobDetailFactoryBean notificationJobDetail() {
        JobDetailFactoryBean bean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        bean.setJobClass(NotificationJob.class);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    CronTriggerFactoryBean notificationCronTrigger() {
        CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        cronTriggerFactoryBean.setCronExpression(schedulerProperty.getCronNotification());
        cronTriggerFactoryBean.setJobDetail(Objects.requireNonNull(notificationJobDetail().getObject()));
        return cronTriggerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        schedulerFactoryBean.setTriggers(notificationCronTrigger().getObject());
        schedulerFactoryBean.setApplicationContextSchedulerContextKey(QUARTZ_APPLICATION_CONTEXT);
        return schedulerFactoryBean;
    }
```

But some how the application.conf properties I guess is not read by Quartz and therefor clustering is not working. In the logs it shows

```
Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
```

Comment: You mentioned the name of your configuration file is application.conf. What happens if you rename it application.yml? Spring Boot will read application.properties and application.yml/yaml configuration files.

Comment: Sorry, its actually application.yaml. Will update the question.

Comment: Spring auto-configuration automatically builds the SchedulerFactoryBean with the configuration from application.yaml file, since SchedulerFactoryBean is being manually created with @Bean annotation, properties needs to be manually set to the bean ref.https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2d2cbff504ae80d82ba628115f972cd40604616b/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzAutoConfiguration.java#L65